Subscribing once to a smart contract event
I am trying to subscribe and then unsubscribe right after using the .once as stated on the web3 1.2.0 documentation (there is none for 4.7.0 which I am using).
But it throws off an error:
Error closing game with ID 1: TypeError: The listener must be a function
    at addListener 

This is the code im using:
async function closeGame(gameID) {
  try {
    // Call the closeGame function in the smart contract
    await contract.methods.closeGame().send(
      { from: '0xe2F6F679C00aB7Dee502eDCa94311C65d2a4532b' }
    );

    // CLOSED CONFIRMATION
    console.log(`Waiting confirmation for game with ID ${gameID} to close...`);
    contract.once('GameClosed', {
      filter: { gameID: gameID },
      fromBlock: 0,
    }, async (error, event) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(`Error handling GameClosed event for game with ID ${gameID}:`, error);
      } else {
        console.log(`Game with ID ${gameID} closed successfully`);
        // Wait for 30 seconds before sending seed to the closed game
        setTimeout(async () => {
          await executeAfterGameClosed(gameID);
        }, 30000);
      }
    });

The transaction does go through, and it fails when using contract.once
This is my event:
event GameClosed(uint256 indexed gameID);
I am not really sure how should I be using .once, I have tried almost everything and there is no docs for 4.7.0
Any help is greatly appreciated :D

If you’re only listening to it once, then why would you need to subscribe it? You can directly extract the event information from the transaction receipt.
